# How to reveal FileInputStream weaknesses?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube 6.5 does not complain about the following code:

```
private static Properties loadProperties(File file) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
    return properties;
}
```

I see at least two weeknesses here:

1. The stream isn't closed
2. [FileInputStream/FileOutputStream are considered harmful](https://dzone.com/articles/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful)

Are there rules to activate, that will detect such weeknesses?